# how to keep scroll position to focus the element after add element in jquery

Tags: jquery

I was stuck in the situation.
 I hope that when I click "add" text in a block, my vertical scroll also move and focus on the point I clicked. 
Before:
[image]

After I click add to clone the element. A block was added and the scroll does not change. My screen show the block which was cloned
[image]
I expect that the scroll change to I trace the item I clicked as bellow:
[image]

I have some jquery code as bellow:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.like').click(function(){
            $(this).html("added");
            $(this).clone().appendTo('#add');
            })
        });
    </script>
    <body>
        <div style="width: 1000px; height: 200px; background: white;"></div>
        <div>--------------------------------------</div>
        <div id="add"></div>
        <div>--------------------------------------</div>
        <div class="container">
            <div style="width: 100px; height: 400px; background: red;" class="like" id ="0"><span>add</span></div>
            <div style="width: 100px; height: 400px; background: blue;" class="like" id ="1"><span >add</span></div>
            <div style="width: 100px; height: 400px; background: yellow;" class="like" id ="2"><span >add</span></div>
            <div style="width: 100px; height: 400px; background: red;" class="like" id ="3"><span >add</span></div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use jquery animate function

```
$('.like').click(function(){
    $(this).html("added");
    $(this).clone().appendTo('#add');

    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 1000);

})
```

The code that I added animates the scroll bar from the top to bottom

You need to get your new div distance from the top and replace `$(document).height()` with it.

examples:

[**Offset()**](http://api.jquery.com/offset/)

```
var height = $("div").offset().top();

$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: height }, 1000);
```

Comment: "I don't know where the new div will be added so I can't tell you the height."
You can see it -  <div id="add"></div>
The new element will be added into the area. I tried running your suggestion, but it does not work. :(

Comment: Maby `$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(".container).offset().top() + $(".container #3).offset().top() }, 1000);`

Answer (score 0):

I found out the answer as bellow:
**Update JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.like').click(function() {
        var x = $(this).offset().top;
        var xx = $(this).position().top-$(window).scrollTop();
         alert($(window).height() +'---' + $(document).height());
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        if ($(this).html() == 'add') {
            $(this).html("added");
            $(this).clone().appen dTo('#add');
            $("html, body").animate({
                scrollTop : xx + $(this).height()
            }, 3000);
        } else {
            $(this).html("add");
            var a = $(this).attr('id');
            $('#add').find('#' + id).remove();
            $("html, body").animate({
                scrollTop : xx - $(this).height() 
            }, 3000);
        }
    })

});
```